# Replace contents of multiple cells in a dataframe

Tags: r

I need to replace the contents of multiple cells in a dataframe. Using `mtcars` as an example, how would I replace any cells which contain `1` with `one` in the *vs* column?

Comment: Am I crazy to think this question seems pretty clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mtcars$vs[mtcars$vs == 1] <- "one"
```

or

```
mtcars[mtcars$vs == 1, "vs"] <- "one"
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
mtcars$vs[mtcars$vs == 1] <- "one"
```

Comment: That code replace any '1' in mtcars with 'one'. I need to work with just a single column. I thought this would work: mtcars[mtcars$VS == 1] = "one"     but it doesnt.

Comment: @RossAhmed: I didn't notice the addition *in the vs column* at my first read through. While editing your question I recognized my error and edit my answer, too.